# Cannot find implementation of glib2-0 library (sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev)

Tags: c, eclipse, include, glib

I'm developing a C project in Eclipse that needs **glib** library functions. I run `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev` and, indeed, at the path */usr/include*, **glib-2.0** appears. The point is that only headers file are in those folder, no implementation (in other words no file with *.c* extension are in there). In fact, compiler gives no error but the linker throw many `undefined reference` to any function/type that are defined in **glib** folder. How can I install properly this library?

Comment: I think you have installed it properly, it's just that you don't link it properly to your project.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? I also added to the proper path to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++build -> Settings: Tool settings tab -> GCC C Linker-> includes` but nothing changes. I also tried to run my project from command line explicitly stating what the needed inclusions are but the same "undefined reference" error comes out. Can you please tell me how to link'em properly? I'm getting crazy

Comment: You need to add libraries somewhere in these settings, can't tell exactly where

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but please don't disparage people for making suggestions even if the suggestion isn't 100% the answer you were looking for. Quite often this is how good answers get made: the problem isn't clear, someone makes a suggestion, and it helps the original asker find the actual problem, and they are then able to post an answer that helps other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> The point is that only headers file are in those folder, no implementation (in other words no file with .c extension are in there)

Development packages do not include the whole source tree, only the files necessary for the development of your own project; namely: header files, pkg-config description files (for determining the compiler and linker flags); and ancillary tools only needed while developing.

> In fact, compiler gives no error but the linker throw many undefined reference to any function/type that are defined in glib folder.

In order to build code that depends on GLib, you need to use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/); pkg-config gives you the list of necessary compiler and linker flags. For instance, if you want to build a GLib-based project, you will need to:

- call `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` to get the list of compiler flags
- call `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` to get the list of linker flags

You will need to add the output of those two commands in the settings for the Compiler flags.

There is also a [pkg-config plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt) in the Eclipse plugin market place that might be helpful to you.